# Create Navigation Property in Entity Framework Without all keys/foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, navigation-properties

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to create an association in EF without the use of all keys.

Below is an example where there is a combination key in author, but I only have 1 part of that key in book. My question is how do I make a Navigation property without all of the keys?

```
[Table("Book")]
public class Book {

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string AuthorLastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}

[Table("Author")]
public class Author {

    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public string AuthorFirstName { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public string AuthorLastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

internal class BookConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Book> {
    public BookConfig()
    {
        HasRequired(hr => hr.Author)
            .WithMany(wm => wm.Books)
            .HasForeignKey(fk => new { 
                fk.AuthorLastName
            });
    }
}
```

This is obviously not going to work since I don't have all of the full combination key in book to associate it to author in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

This will give you a manual control on the key; But the Table in the database must have a primary key! I'm wonderung why ou need something like that I think the problem somewhere else.

Comment: I am working with a Dynamics Nav table structure, which leaves me no choice in modifying which keys are in which tables, even though they have relations directly like the above. I don't write any records, I only read from this database. Its not exactly Code-first since I am manually mapping to an already created database and I would like to create what would act as Navigation properties without the full compound key in the collection table. Unfortunately the above solution does not solve my problem.

Comment: Why not use database first then?

Comment: @reggaeguitar I'm not sure if he use Database first can he create a partial entities I'm not sure and If he can do that I do not think this will be a good Job.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @JotaBe; So you can Change the your relationship 1..n and than use eager loading with/without lazy loading.

Comment: I can't use database first because of the table structure. such as tables company1$item and company2$item. For my application, I tell it what company to run against and the DataModel gets built from that. It takes companyName + "$" + tableName("item") to build the table mappings during the buildModel. This allows me to focus the application on 1 company per instance. Book and Author is just a basic example of a more complicated problem. Is there any way to emulate a Navigation property to act the way I want. In my case it is practical  to obtain a list by 1 field of the parents compound key.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because it's a many to many relation.

In your example, if you only take `AuthorLastName` there can be several authors with the same last name. So there are many elements in this side of the relation. And obviously there are many books on the other side (an author can write many books).

So, definitely, you cannot model it as a one-to-many relation.

Fortunately, [someone has explained this problem of books and authors before.](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/06/13/many-to-many-relationships-with-ef.aspx).